# How to fix the width of the select box in dojo using html

Tags: html, dojo

Hi I have a select box for which I have kept some width, the options for the select box are coming from a rest service, which has a list of names, now the issue is, depending on the width of the name , the select box width is changing which I dont want. I want to keep the select box width as constant, and if the list name is exceeding the width of a select box then the list has break, can anyone help me on this?

```
<select class="myClass" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select"
data-dojo-attach-point="dapContentId"
data-dojo-props="id:'dapContentId',name:'dapContentId'">
</select>
.myClass   {
  overflow : scroll;
  width:200px !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: black;
  white-space: no-wrap !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10190419/285288), you can use CSS for that:

```css
.tundra .dijitSelect .dijitButtonText {
    text-align: left;
}

.tundra .dijitSelectLabel {
    width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```